# Validation Error: Value is not valid for SelectManyCheckBox

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am new to JSF, I am getting the following error for `<h:selectManyCheckBox>`:

> Validation Error: Value is not valid

This is my model:

```
private List<String> selectedRoles;
public List<SelectItem> availableRolesSelectItem;

for (Role role : rolesList) {
    SelectItem option = new SelectItem(role.getName(), role.getName() + " " + role.getDescription());
    availableRolesSelectItem.add(option);
}
```

This is my view:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{mybean.selectedRoles}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{errormessages.valueRequired}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.availableRolesSelectItem}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

In the `SelectItem` I am not assigning `Role` object as item value, I am just assigning a `String` value. Even though I am getting the error.

Can you guys help me on this?

Comment: enough description is provided here http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/09/validate-required-checkbox.html

Comment: @madhu: this only applies to `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`.

Answer (score 4):

You get this error whenever the selected value(s) doesn't match any of the available values during the request of processing the form submit. You need to ensure that the `availableRolesSelectItem` is **exactly the same** during the request of processing the form submit as it was during displaying the form. Ideally, you would do the `availableRolesSelectItem` filling job in the bean's (post)constructor.

Comment: If I could upvote this a million times I would.

Comment: What do I do if they can't be exactly the same, ex they are search results loaded from a typeahead query?